# Supply more than one alternatives image source for img html tag?

Tags: javascript, html

I have two alternative images and one image as default in case the first two images are not found.

```
<img 
    src='image1.png'
    onError="this.onerror=null;this.src='image2.png';"
    onError="this.onerror=null;this.src='default.png';" />
```

Then I tested on three `<img />` I found `image1.png` and `image2.png` works correctly but in case there are not `image1.png` and `image2.png`, the default image `default.png` does not display.

Any tips on how can I use more than one alternative images like my case above?

Comment: Browser ignores duplicate attributes

Comment: you could implement a handler for the function then you can do what ever logic you need.

Comment: @charlietfl, I tested with `onError="this.onerror=null;this.src='image2.png';this.src='default.png';` the same `onError` attribute, but still does not work.

Comment: try this.src='image2.png'||'default.png';

Comment: @DanielA.White, I have no clue to check if image exist or not, could you please supply the snippet code ? Thanks

Comment: @kapilpandey That really doesn't make sense since the first string is truthy

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may want to use `addEventListener` instead, keeping track of your position in an array of possible images.

```
<img src='image1.png'/>
<script>
function addFallbackSources(img, sources){
  let idx = 0;
  img.addEventListener("error", e=>{
      if(idx >= sources.length) throw new Error("No images left to try");
      img.src = sources[idx++];
  });
}
addFallbackSources(document.querySelector('img'), ["image2.png", "default.png"]);
</script>
```

Comment: excuse me, could I ask how can I hide error message 404 (NOT FOUND) in console on Event Handler `onError` ? Thanks

Comment: @HouyNarun I'm afraid that cannot be done. Also, my username is "hev1", not "hav1".

Comment: You're still keeping track of the index, just not on the tag, which makes it less extendable.

Comment: @Bren I don't think it's very hard to extend it by making use of closures.

Comment: @hev1 why would you not associate the alternate sources with the image itself? In your answer, you just have a global variable which assumes all images will use those as sources.

Comment: @Bren No, it does not assume anything. I have created a function that can handle any images with any sources. Perhaps you will understand better if it was written inline: `addFallbackSources(document.querySelector('img'),  ["image2.png", "default.png"]);`

Comment: @Bren It seems that you were confused by the name of the function parameters.

Comment: @hev1 your code assumes all images will use `image2.png` and `default.png`.

Comment: @Bren My code does not assume that at all. You can call `addFallbackSources` with any image element and any array of sources. For example: `addFallbackSources(document.getElementById("image1"), ["a.png", "b.png"])` (Although this is completely irrelevant, I did not downvote your answer.)

Comment: @Bren Yes, it only works for the first `img` tag, but I'm sure people know how to select other image tags themselves. What you're saying is only a matter of style.

Comment: I just see it as a naive solution. I'm sure we can deduce that the OP simply wanted a way of handling onerror of one or more images, not just one.

Comment: @Bren They can handle multiple images by invoking the function multiple times. Some people like to separate their JavaScript from HTML; it's a matter of preference.

Answer (score 2):

You could add a `data-alt-src` attribute that holds the values of the alternates, then have the `onerror` attribute call the `loadAltImage` function that simply loads the next alternate image index. This will essentially call itself recursively.

```
<img src="image1.png" data-alt-src="image2.png,default.png" onerror="loadAltImage(this)" />
```

```
function loadAltImage(element) {
  const alternatives = element.dataset.altSrc.split(',');
  const nextLoadIndex = parseInt(element.dataset.loadIndex || 0);
  
  if(nextLoadIndex < alternatives.length) {
    element.src = alternatives[nextLoadIndex].trim();
    element.dataset.loadIndex = nextLoadIndex + 1;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

**Something Like follows may work.**

```js
function setNextAvailableImage(element, image_list) {
    const current_img = element.src
    let next_img = 'default.png'
    let found_index = -1
    for (let i = 0; i < image_list.length; i ++) {
        if (current_img.indexOf(image_list[i]) != -1) {
            found_index = i
            break
        }
    }

    if (found_index == -1 && image_list.length > 0) {
        element.src = image_list[0]
    }
    else if (found_index + 1 < image_list.length) {
        next_img = image_list[found_index + 1]
        element.src = next_img
    } else {
        element.src = next_img
    }
    
}
```

```html
<img src='image1.png' onError="setNextAvailableImage(this, ['image2.png', 'image3.png'])"/>
```